# ColdFusion - how to set Content-Length header

Tags: coldfusion, http-headers, content-length

Has anyone successfully added a Content-Length header to regular ColdFusion (I'm using CF9) pages? I'm setting up a new server behind a Cisco load balancer with compression - the box refuses to compress anything without this header, but CF doesn't pass it by default.

`<cfheader name="Content-Length" value="something">` will set the header, but finding the right value is a problem.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if you have control over the load balancer, but I believe that the default configuration of cisco load balancers is that it only compresses content over 512 bytes in length.  But, this is a configuration value (minimum-size in the compression settings), and can be changed, and I'm pretty sure it can be changed to just compress everything (with the proper accepts header on the request, obv.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've solved it:

`<cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#getPageContext().getCFOutput().getBuffer().size()#">`

I stuck that in o`nRequestEnd()` and the Cisco box is happily compressing away.

Thanks for the input folks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't love this idea, but could you make some sort of wrapper with cfsavecontent and take the length of that?

Something like:

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="yes">
<cfsavecontent variable="testVar">
     <cfinclude template="myPage.cfm">
</cfsavecontent>
<cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#len(testVar)#">
<cfoutput>#testVar#</cfoutput>
```

I'm not sure if the count would be off due to white space issues.

Comment: easy, <cfoutput>#trim(testVar)#</cfoutput> ?