# Mod_security blocking embedded Video from loading on ColdFusion page due to byte range

Tags: coldfusion, http-headers, mod-security

Within our CMS, previews of an article which contains a HTML5 embedded  (mp4), causes the video to being blocked by following rule in mod_security. It gives a 403 forbidden message in the console:

```
This rule compares the first and second byte ranges and flags when the first value is greater than the second.

 -=[ References ]=-
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2011/Aug/175

3. Identifies an excessive number of byte range fields within one request
```

Currently our development environment is not configured with mod_security, so I need to resolve this by deploying code onto the acceptance server, so understand I'm trying to avoid trial and error.

Should I be using either:

```
<cfheader name="Accept-Ranges" value="">
```

or

```
<cfheader name="Content-Range" value="">
```

And how is it best to calculate the 'range' or just 'length'? The temptation is to stick a wildcard `*` in there.

I've read about a potential solution here
[ColdFusion - how to set Content-Length header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928431/coldfusion-how-to-set-content-length-header) , but it doesn't sound foolproof.

Comment: I feel I have misinterpreted the message, too many 'byte range' fields. however using the live http headers plugin for firefox, there is not one record of 'byte' or 'range' within them.